# Nohup vs Nohup &

Tags: linux, shell, nohup

I am having trouble understanding the difference between using just nohup to run a script and using nohup and '&'. I understand that for the latter, if I want to kill it, I can just kill the process id. But for the former, can I just hit "CTRL+C" to kill the script. So if I were to run the below command

> nohup sh script.sh

and then exit out of it by hitting "CTRL+C", will that script still be running or not?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It would be better if you would understand what's going on.

`nohup` set's the process to ignore `HUP` signal. That's all. Nothing more nothing less. When does a process receive a `HUP` signal? Usually when a terminal logouts. And the default action on `HUP` signal is to terminate.

`hitting "CTRL+C"` just sends `INT` signal to the process. The default action (and you can `trap "echo something" INT` override it too) is to terminate the process.

`nohup sh script.sh` upon receiving `INT` signal will terminate (assuming `script.sh` didn't specially handle the `INT` signal) as it didn't set up a custom action on receiving a `INT` signal and it will ignore `HUP` signal.

The `&` placed after a command runs it in the background. As a separate process. So `sh script.sh &` runs `sh` in the background. The process will still terminate if you send it `INT` signal, just `CTRL+C` doesn't send it to *that* process, but to process that is in foreground. You can send it still using `kill` command. And the command will still terminate when the terminal exits, when the process receives the `HUP` signal.

So running `nohup sh script.sh &` will run the process in the background and ignore the signal that is send when the terminal exits. But still it will terminate on receiving `INT` signal. Just pressing `CTRL+C` in terminal will not send it to this process, as shell sends the term signal to the foreground process, not the background one.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. The advantage of & is that you avoid having to press Ctrl+C
See for instance https://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm